# Intercom fetch articles with Redux gives CORS error

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, intercom

I am trying to fetch all articles from our intercom but I keep getting CORS error in local environment.

My API looks like this (the 'hardcodedToken' is our temporarily hardcoded Bearer token for development purposes

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const intercomApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'intercomApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://api.intercom.io/',
    prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
      const accessToken = 'hardcodedToken';
      if (accessToken) {
        headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      }
      return headers;
    }
  }),

  tagTypes: ['Article'],
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getIntercomLatestUpdatesArticles: build.query<Article[], void>({
      query: () => 'articles',
      providesTags: ['Article'],
transformResponse: (response: { results: Article[] }) => {
        const filteredResponse: Article[] = response.results.filter(
          (item: Article) => item.parent_id === 5388628
        );
        return filteredResponse.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id).slice(0, 2);
      }
  })
});

export const { useGetIntercomLatestUpdatesArticlesQuery } = intercomApi;
export interface Article {
  id: number;
  type: string;
  workspace_id: string;
  parent_id: number | null;
  parent_type: string;
  parent_ids: number[];
  title: string;
  description: string;
  body: string;
  author_id: number;
  url: string;
  state: string;
  tags?: string[];
  created_at?: number;
  updated_at?: number;
}
```

[image]

I tried pretty much everything I could find but I still can't get it to work. I tried deploying it into development environment and it's getting the same error.

Is there something wrong with my api?
I do get the data without problem with postman.

Comment: CORS has nothing to do with react or redux. It's your browser that refuses to send requests to intercom. If intercom does not offer a solution for that on their side (the server side) you need to use a reverse proxy, as it is commonly done with create-react-app for example. There already are a lot of SO answers around this topic.

Comment: I was fetching it based on this https://developers.intercom.com/docs/references/rest-api/api.intercom.io/Articles/listArticles/ 
They don't mention needing something special to do the fetch.

Comment: Because you can always call the API from the "Backend" so your API, Postman, curl etc. But if CORS is not configured then other websites cannot call this API on the frontend side.

Comment: Ah that makes sense :) I'll make the call in the backend then. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem with your API not with your frontend. Your API needs to be configured to allow calls from different domains. It is working from Postman because Postman does not check if you are allowed to do the call. But browsers do check this. Your API needs to return headers which states what domains are allowed to access it. If they wouldn't check this then any website you enter would be able to call any online API as you as long you are logged in to this API. Thanks to CORS, API can tell the browser which domains really can do requests to it protecting you as a user.
So basically, you need to return this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'
```

but from your API. BTW - such broad access is not a good idea for production environments usually as you probably do not want for any website to be able to call this API.

Example debug settings (not for production) for .NET core (if the API is in the .NET core of course):

```
 builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddDefaultPolicy(
   policy => policy
   .WithExposedHeaders("*")
   .AllowAnyOrigin()
   .AllowAnyHeader()));
```

Comment: Intercom is a known and widely used service, they won't let OP modify their response headers, neither did OP hint at using .NET in any way.

Comment: @timotgl I didn't know that but still my response is valid. Its on the API side not on the frontend side.

Comment: I know such broad access is not a good idea, it would be adjusted as I keep working on it but I can't get it to fetch even with a broad access. I'm not using .NET.

Comment: So as I responded - you need to modify the backend not the frontend. If this is not your API then you need to request this configuration from the API provider. If this is not possible - you need to have your own API which will call the destination API and your frontend will have to call your API as a proxy.